# How can you use conda to install modules in an existing virtualenv (created with Poetry)

Tags: python, anaconda, apple-m1, python-poetry

I use Poetry to manage my virtual environments because it enables a production-ready and repeatable installation process.

But there are specific libraries (mostly scientific modules with C/C++ dependencies) whose builds fail on macOS with an M1 chip, and it is hard to prepare to fix their build when you have a long list of dependencies.

Is it possible to use conda to build/install those libraries inside an existing virtualenv?